# list column header font size too small

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view

The font of column headers of the SharePoint 2013 List/Library is too small. Can we increase the size without writing code (changes the css classes)?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Edit your view page.
- Add Script Editor.
- Add the following Style .

> ```
> <style>
> .ms-vh2 {
> font-size: 20pt ! important; }
> .ms-vh {
> font-size: 20pt ! important; }
> </style>
> ```

[image]

**To apply this for all lists within the site.**

- Create a CSS file
- add the above style.
- upload CSS file to your style library in sharePoint site.
- If you are using a publishing site go to Site Settings > Master Page > at alternate CSS URL > Browse to your CSS file.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use below style to override the font size

```
.ms-vh {
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```